# Django - Saving formset data with different values

Tags: django, django-forms

I have such models:

```
class House(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s' % self.name

class Rooms(models.Model):
  house = models.ForeignKey(House, null=True)
  room = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
  people = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s' % self.room

class People(models.Model):
  room = models.ForeignKey(Rooms, null=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s' % self.surname
```

So if in the house there are two rooms with two people in each room i need to save two `People` instances with one `room` key and the second with other `room` key instead of this my code saves four `People` instances in each `Rooms`.

My code looks like this:

```
for people in people_formset:
  name = adult_tourists.cleaned_data['name']
  surname = adult_tourists.cleaned_data['surname']
  for room in house.rooms_set.all():
    for people in range(room.people):
      p = People.objects.create(room=room, name=name, surname=surname)
      p.save()
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list where each room appears once for each person it can contain. You can then zip the formset forms and the list together, and create the person for each form.

```
# creates a list of lists e.g. [[room1, room1], [room2], [room3]]
room_lists = [[room] * room.people for room in house.rooms_set.all()]

# flatten the list e.g. [room1, room1, room2, room3]
rooms = [room for room_list in room_lists for room in room_list]

# zip the lists together
for form, room in zip(people_formset, rooms):
    name = form.cleaned_data['name']
    surname = form.cleaned_data['surname']
    p = People.objects.create(room=room, name=name, surname=surname)
```

The code may require further changes, for example to handle the case where there are more people than places in rooms.